# Validation add in AWS S3 bucket signed url in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am generating AWS s3 bucket signed url for the image upload but I want to make restrict the signed URL.

I want to add the below validation as a mime type.

1. Only for accept the jpeg or png file
2. The image size should be less than 2 MB.

```
// Set up the S3 client
$client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-south-1',
]);

$command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => "bucket_name",
    'Key' => "key",
]);

$presignedRequest = $client->createPresignedRequest($command, '+20 minutes');

echo (string) $presignedRequest->getUri();
```

Below composer package use
**"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.273.5"**

I have already added the "Conditions" inside the "getCommand" but it is didn't work

```
$command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
    'conditions' => [
        ['acl' => 'private'], // Restrict access to private ACL
        ['eq', '$Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'], // Restrict to JPEG files only
        ['starts-with', '$key', 'path/to/'], // Restrict to a specific path prefix
    ]
]);
```

when uploading using a signed URL and the image and the above validation is violated then return the error.

Comment: Could you share the error logs you were getting here?

Comment: He didn't return any error and the image was uploaded to the AWS bucket.